# How to change overflow style to hidden when modal opens

Tags: css, reactjs, styles, styled-components

I am trying to create react app and i want overflow to hidden when button is pressed,
i want to display contact form on modal but overflow is running everything i can scroll even with modal is open

Here is my navbar with button

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { FaBars, FaTimes } from "react-icons/fa";
import "./Navbar.css";
import { IconContext } from "react-icons/lib";
import Button from "./Button";
import Modal from "./Contact Form/Modal";
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";

export default function Navbar() {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
  const [button, setButton] = useState(true);
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);

  function closeModal() {
    setModalOpen(false);
  }

  function openModal() {
    setModalOpen(true);
  }

  function handleClick() {
    setClick(!click);
  }

  function closeMobileMenu() {
    setClick(false);
  }

  function showButton() {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 960) {
      setButton(false);
    } else {
      setButton(true);
    }
  }

  function closeMobileMenu() {
    setClick(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    showButton();
  }, []);

  window.addEventListener("resize", showButton);

  return (
    <>
      <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: "#fff" }}>
        <div className="navbar">
          <div className="navbar-container container">
            <Link to="/" className="navbar-logo" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
              LOGO
            </Link>
            <div className="menu-icon" onClick={handleClick}>
              {click ? <FaTimes /> : <FaBars />}
            </div>
            <ul className={click ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to="/" className="nav-links" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                  Home
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to="/" className="nav-links" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                  About Us
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to="/" className="nav-links" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                  Contact Us
                </Link>
              </li>
              {/* Main button */}
              <li className="nav-btn">
                {button ? (
                  <Link to='' className="btn-link">
                    <motion.button
                      whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
                      whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
                      className="btn--outline"
                      onClick={() => (modalOpen ? closeModal() : openModal())} //modal opens
                    >
                      CONTACT US
                    </motion.button>
                  </Link>
                ) : (
                  <Link
                    to=""
                    className="btn-link"
                    onClick={closeMobileMenu}
                  >
                    <motion.button
                      whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
                      whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
                      className="btn--mobile"
                      buttonSize='btn--mobile'
                      buttonStyle='btn--outline'
                      onClick={() => {(modalOpen ? closeModal() : openModal())}} //modal opens
                    >
                      Contact US
                    </motion.button>
                  </Link>
                )}
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <AnimatePresence
          // Disable any initial animations on children that
          // are present when the component is first rendered
          initial={false}
          // Only render one component at a time.
          // The exiting component will finish its exit
          // animation before entering component is rendered
          exitBeforeEnter={true}
          // Fires when all exiting nodes have completed animating out
          onExitComplete={() => null}
        >
          {modalOpen && <Modal modalOpen={modalOpen} handleClose={closeModal} />}
        </AnimatePresence>
      </IconContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}
```

I was trying to do it use State but it didn't work. I use style effect but i didn't manage to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

You will make a boolean state with an initial value set to false.

When the button is clicked you will update the state from false to true and I will recommend it for you instead of making it true. then you will use this state easily with your style property and do what you need.

change the style bellow based on your needs.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 style={{ display: clicked ? "none" : "block" }}>Hello 
       CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={() => setClicked(!clicked)}>click</button> <= here instead of making it true. I made it the oppesite of the previous value. to toggle between them.
    </div>
  );
}
```